# Как сделать проверку url на валидность?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте, уважаемые друзья!
Т.к. я на php только перебрался, а реализовать то, о чём пойдёт речь ниже нужно срочно, прошу помощи у Вас.
Как сделать проверку url на валидность?
URL должен соответствовать след. случаю:

> http://www.uztest.ru/некоторый 
> текст.gif

Некоторый текст может включать любые англ. буквы, цифры, слэш(/), нижнее подчёркивание(_)
Спасибо вам огромное! ОГРОМНОЕ! 
Обещаю выучить регулярки в скором времени.

Comment: Никогда не видел чтобы *Некоторый текст* мог включать *слэш* учитывая что это названия файли или директории!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match("/^http:\/\/www.uztest.ru\/[0-9a-z_\/]*.gif/",$url);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = 'aaj66_/';
//$text = 'aaj 66_ /';

if(preg_match("/^[a-z0-9_\/.]+$/", $text))
{
    echo 'Ok';
}
else
{
    echo 'Bad';
}
```

И на счет слеша лучше бы подумать!

Вмеcто `$text` подставите - `trim('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`